# neomodel doesn't save nodes in database

Tags: django, neo4j, neomodel

I have a neomodel model:

```
class User(StructuredNode):
    id = UniqueIdProperty()
    username = StringProperty(unique_index=True)
    email = StringProperty(unique_index=True)
    password = StringProperty()

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.password = make_password(self.password)
        return super(User, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

When I save a new instance of such model in the console, I get a new User instance successfully, but when I retrieve all **User** objects from model, I get an empty resultset:

```
(AttractoraVenv) MacBook-Pro-de-Hugo:AttractoraBackend hugovillalobos$ python manage.py shell
Python 3.7.1 (default, Dec 14 2018, 13:28:58)
[Clang 4.0.1 (tags/RELEASE_401/final)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
(InteractiveConsole)
>>> from users.models import User
>>> user = User(username='admin', email='admin@admin.com', password='secret').save()
>>> user
<User: {'id': '0d3b0aa56499414d8fb205ea1279662e', 'username': 'admin', 'email': 'admin@admin.com', 'password': 'pbkdf2_sha2
56$150000$vTdAnqAvXnOM$0hPMc1KiMpLvHbVO4C77OXUa9dmKzt9lMxIg8Ig+za8='}>
>>> User.nodes.all()
[]
```

I don't know what I am missing.

**EDIT**

I found that when I create a User instance using cypher from **neo4j** console, `User.nodes.all()` returns such instance. So I guess the problem is on `User.save()`. I also found that `User.save()` works well when updating, so the problem is on create.

Answer (score 2):

`id` is a built-in attribute and it's not a good idea to override it. You can replace `id = UniqueIdProperty()` with something like `userid = UniqueIdProperty()` and that should address the issue.

Comment: can you link the the docs that say id is a built-in? I just had this problem and it took me a while to find this post.

Comment: Just stumbled on this answer and it helped me figure out why save() seemed to be failing silently. See https://neomodel.readthedocs.io/en/latest/properties.html?highlight=id#unique-identifiers for more details advising against app use of ID and the UniqueIdProperty alternative

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure overriding the `save` method is the good way to go.

Try this instead (remove completely the `save` method):

```
class User(StructuredNode):
    id = UniqueIdProperty()
    username = StringProperty(unique_index=True)
    email = StringProperty(unique_index=True)
    password = StringProperty()

    def pre_save(self):
        self.password = make_password(self.password)
```

Comment: Nope, exactly the same :(